# Implicits compiler bug?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit

First, a short description.  It seems that if I put an implicit for some other type in a companion object and import that implicit into scope of the class it isn't found during implicit resolution until it is referenced explicitly once(or defined above the class).  Example below.

```
class A(val a: Something)

object A {
  implicit val default = ... //found by default
}

object B {
  def func(fn: => T)(implicit a: A) = ...
}

class Broken {
  def doSomething = {
    import Broken._ // or Broken.actual
    B.func { ... } // Uses A.default, not Broken.actual for implicit
  }
}

object Broken {
  implicit val actual = ...
}

class Fixed {
  def doSomething = {
    import Fixed._
    println(actual) //reference actual
    B.func { ... } // uses Fixed.actual
  }
}

object Fixed {
  implicit val actual = ...
}

object WTF {
  implicit val actual = ...
}

class WTF {
  def doSomething = {
    import WTF._
    B.func { ... } // With object definition first this works without referencing actual
  }
}
```

I am kind of assuming at this point I've found a compiler bug, so I'll open a jira against Scala, but in the mean time I'm wondering if anyone here knows if this is expected, or if there's already an open bug for this?

edit: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7830

edit2: removed ": A" type declaration from all actual and default vals to properly recreate my issue.

Comment: 1. Don't open JIRA issues before you've confirmed it's a real issue. 2. Can you post a working example that demonstrates your problem? Cos I just tried it inserting some values and it worked as expected. http://ideone.com/oELulq

Comment: Well shoot, there is one difference here between what I posted and my actual code.  If you remove : A from all actual and default declarations this now works as I've described above.

Comment: http://ideone.com/1Vtepf for the issue

Comment: Wow. In a nutshell, putting the object before the class that uses an implicit from the object changes implicit resolution. Wild!  It has to be wrong, right? I also tried it with the classes outside `object Main`, because objects have initialization order; not sure if package source is supposed to have the same notion, but I guess it does.

Comment: In my actual code A and B are in one package, Broken/etc are in a different one.

Comment: Can confirm that removing type annotation on `actual` in `Broken` object does change behaviour - was going to say that it must be a bona fide bug but according to paulp below it's not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, this is "as specified" to the extent that there is a specification. The "specification" is buried in the comments of a ticket from five years ago. https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-801

Comment: Hmm, so I did see something similar to what I have.  There are examples of "this doesn't compile" which is an issue if I take the implicit default out of A above.  My problem is quite insidious though since if I do have a default implicit it finds it, my program compiles, and seemingly works!  Maybe with my example it'll get revisited, but who knows.

Comment: @WilliamThurston There's that warning about ambiguous implicits (or whatever) where it says "such-and-such doesn't apply because it comes later and lacks an explicit result type."  So generally I always write the result type, but frankly, that didn't cross my mind when I looked at this issue.  (I should say, "...my mind, what's left of it.")  On the upside, I sense a puzzler coming on.  Scala bugs come and go, but puzzlers are for the ages.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems this is expected as you pointed out.  I don't even get a compiler warning either from the way the code is written above though :(  Maybe some day I'll go look at the Scala internals and justify to myself why this has to be this way.  Given that the Jira was closed as well I guess I just need to deal with it.